# Is there a parser/script to get data from github

Tags: parsing, curl, github

We recently started using GitHub+ZenHub as a project management tool. I'm looking for a way to get data from github for my manager to easily put in update emails she has to send weekly. I was able to connect to our github instance with curl command but it's pulling a lot of data I don't need.

```
curl -u user:token -i https://github.ibm.com/api/v3/issues
```

All I need is to get stuff like all updates added to certain issue, or list all updates posted by certain person. So far I wasn't able to write a proper curl command to get info on only one issue for example. Also am I correct that curl used with `user:token` gets only information about issues created by the `user` and not all from whole repository?

I read through the GitHub APIv3 documentation but no luck. I don't know how to narrow my command to give me only what I want.

Do you know if there is any tool that would help me to get the raw data? I know GitHub 2.10 has new API, but we're still using 2.9.5 and there's no telling when we will update.

Answer (score 0):

> All I need is to get stuff like all updates added to certain issue, or list all updates posted by certain person. So far I wasn't able to write a proper curl command to get info on only one issue for example.

Have you seen this page?

https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#get-a-single-issue

For example if your repository is at `https://github.com/user/repo`,
then you can use these queries to get info about issue `#5`:

```
curl -sL api.github.com/repos/user/repo/issues/5/
curl -sL api.github.com/repos/user/repo/issues/5/comments
curl -sL api.github.com/repos/user/repo/issues/5/events
```

In case of public repositories, the above works even without authentication.

As a tip, I recommend piping these commands to `jq . | less` for nice readable formatting.

You can get public events by a specific user with another API endpoint:

https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-events-performed-by-a-user